# sqlite linking error

Tags: sqlite, ld

I have a strange link error with SQLite. I have the following code:

```
void TestSQLiteTemp()
{
  /* sqlite3_initialize(); */
  sqlite3_close( db );
}
```

I can compile and link and everything is fine:

```
perdue@minervatest04> ldd bin/tests 
    libCAENVME.so => /usr/lib/libCAENVME.so (0x00002afaffc42000)
    ...
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /home/perdue/software/minervadaq/minervadaq/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00002afafff8f000)
    ...
```

But, if I uncomment the sqlite3_initialize line, ld fails:

```
g++  -o tests TestSuite.o -L/home/perdue/software/minervadaq/minervadaq/lib -lhardware -lminerva_workers -L/usr/lib64 -ldl -L/work/software/CAENVMElib/lib/x86_64 -lCAENVME -L/usr/local/lib -llog4cpp -L/usr/lib64 -lpthread  -L/usr/lib64  -L/home/perdue/software/minervadaq/minervadaq/sqlite/lib/ -lsqlite3
TestSuite.o: In function TestSQLiteTemp():
/home/perdue/software/minervadaq/minervadaq/tests/TestSuite.cpp:199: undefined reference to `sqlite3_initialize'
```

Does anyone know why some functions might be okay, but others fail to link?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the problem was that there was an older version of sqlite in /usr/lib64 and I had that appearing in my linker list before the custom install area. If I move my custom lib area to the front of the list of library paths, everything works.